# PHP Query posts and add unqueried posts to end

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

Okay, so through Wordpress, I've utimately ended up with a query string of the following:

```
"SELECT * FROM wp_z4azbl_posts 
LEFT JOIN wp_z4azbl_postmeta ON(
    wp_z4azbl_posts.ID = wp_z4azbl_postmeta.post_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_z4azbl_term_relationships ON(
    wp_z4azbl_posts.ID = wp_z4azbl_term_relationships.object_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_z4azbl_term_taxonomy ON(
    wp_z4azbl_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_z4azbl_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id) 
LEFT JOIN wp_z4azbl_terms ON(
    wp_z4azbl_terms.term_id = wp_z4azbl_term_taxonomy.term_id) 
WHERE wp_z4azbl_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'opportunitytype' 
AND wp_z4azbl_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND wp_z4azbl_posts.post_type = 'opportunities' 
AND wp_z4azbl_postmeta.meta_key = 'date_timestamp' 
GROUP BY wp_z4azbl_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_z4azbl_postmeta.meta_value ASC"
```

Ultimately this works.  It grabs my posts with a timestamp custom field and sorts it in ascending order.  However, I need it to also append posts that don't have a timestamp after all the posts that have a timestamp.

So right now, it showing something like this:

```
Event Title
January 1, 2011

Event Title 2
January 2, 2011
```

But I want it to append all posts without a timestamp:

```
Event Title
January 1, 2011

Event Title 2
January 2, 2011

Event Title Nostamp

Event Title Nostamp 2
```

How would I alter my query to get this to work?

**EDIT**

Sorry, I messed up on my original query.  I actually need them to sort in ascending order with the non-timestamp posts still at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include rows without a timestamp in the resultset, move `meta_key = 'date_timestamp'` from the `where` clause to `on`:

```
LEFT JOIN 
        wp_z4azbl_postmeta 
ON      wp_z4azbl_posts.ID = wp_z4azbl_postmeta.post_id
        and wp_z4azbl_postmeta.meta_key = 'date_timestamp'
```

Since you are sorting `descending`, the `null` values will already appear on the bottom.  `null` is treated as the lowest possible value for purposes of sorting.

EDIT: To sort `null` differently, use a `case`:

```
order by
        case
        when wp_z4azbl_postmeta.meta_value is null then 2
        else 1
        end
,       wp_z4azbl_postmeta.meta_value
```

Comment: This works great, however I messed up, I actually need them in ascending order, but still need the ones without timestamps below ones with a timestamp.  Is this an easy fix?

Comment: @Josh Allen: You could use a `case`, example added to answer

Comment: You are just absolutely awesome.  Works exactly as needed! Thank you so much!